# Identify movie with man waking up in a maze of machinery

Tags: identify-this-movie

The opening scene is of a man lying in the underground darkness half-buried in muck.  A light comes on briefly and then he is plunged back into total darkness.  As he slowly regains consciousness, he begins to extract himself from the muck.  The light continues to snap on and off as we begin to see more of his surroundings.  With much effort he finally struggles to his feet and tries to find his way out the maze of machinery he is surrounded by.  He climbs upwards and is faced by mysterious, complex mechanisms that spring to life if manipulated correctly.  There is no dialogue.  He seems to be at a total loss as to how he got there.

A captivating and compelling open sequence.  Some "B" SciFi movies (like Cube) are so cool.  Any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly sure you're looking for [Eden Log](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1087842/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (2007)

[image]

> A man wakes up deep inside a cave. Suffering amnesia, he has no recollection of how he came to be here or of what happened to the man whose body he finds beside him. Tailed by a mysterious creature, he must continue through this strange and fantastic world. Enclosed, Tolbiac has no other option to reach the surface than to use REZO ZERO, secret observing cells in this cemetery-like abandoned mine. He embarks upon this journey guided by the roots of a plant, leading the way and the main subject of attention of the REZO.

The beginning of the movie is exactly as you describe and even though this is the only details you have offered I feel confident in answering because you've described the scene precisely.

Here's a [link to the trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vagpjjjY1tI) where you can see glimpses of the protagonist climbing out of the muck.

Comment: Yes, Dannie, that's the one!  Hard to Google when you don't have any info.  If you are a SciFi fan, be sure to check out Cube or Run, Lola, Run! if you haven't seen them already.    Thanks again, Peace be with you.

Comment: This is a good movie, although the end after the solution was kinda useless, would have had more impact if the movie ended at the solution to the questions.